# Find name of object with ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have two classes **User** and **Schedule**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :startdate, :schedule_id, :password, :username
  belongs_to :schedule
end

class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :users
end
```

I want to create a View in which I print the name of an Object Schedule filtered by User:

```
<table>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.id %></td>
    <td><%= user.username %></td>
    <td><%= user.password %></td>
    <td><%= user.startdate %></td>
    <td><%= Schedule.find(user.schedule_id).name %></td>  # <<< This is what I want to do!
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

When I execute this, I get "Couldn't find Schedule without an ID"

How can I do this? Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Is that line giving you an error? Would you describe the current behaviour?

Comment: Try using the association: `user.schedule` will return the associated schedule. Thus you could try `user.schedule.name` if all your associations are set up correctly.

Comment: @ThomasKlemm this is what I get when I try it: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Somewhere you've got a user whose schedule_id is blank which is the reason for your error (in your otherwise correct but clumsy solution. Using an association is more rails-like)

Comment: @FrederickCheung That solved it, thanks!! What exactly do you mean by "using an association"?

Comment: See andrew's answer and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see anything syntactically wrong with your code. Please provide the error if it's generating one. To follow Ruby on Rails conventions you should just be able to do:

```
<td><%= user.schedule && user.schedule.name %></td>
```

The `&&` is in case the user has no schedule assigned.

Comment: well this actually works, if every user is associated with a schedule_id duh;-)